# error: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/JudoPedia/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'JudoPedia' from project 'JudoPedia')

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

I know this has been asked before but it seems like no one knows the answer. So I'm giving it one more shot.

`npx eas build` is producing an error where it can't find main.jsbundle in the directory. But it is there! And it is referenced in Xcode build phases.

One thing I noticed is that it is looking for the main.jsbundle in a path `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/JudoPedia` but that's not where the app is. Everyone who's been asking this question has the same path `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/<projectName>/main.jsbundle`.

[image]
[image]
[image]